# Yii2 MySQL - How to use findUniqueIndexes method?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I read from here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-mysql-schema.html#findUniqueIndexes()-detail

`findUniqueIndexes()` returns all unique indexes for the given table.

---

Here what I did so far:

```
$table = \Yii::$app->db->schema->getTableSchema('my_tbl');

$dbSchema = new \yii\db\mysql\Schema();

$uniqueKeys = $dbSchema->findUniqueIndexes($table);
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function createCommand() on null'

in /media/yahya/Data/my-projects/yii2-api-template-dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php:232

Stack trace:
#0 /media/yahya/Data/my-projects/yii2-api-template-dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(322): yii\db\mysql\Schema->getCreateTableSql(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
#1 /media/yahya/Data/my-projects/yii2-api-template-dev/console/controllers/RevmigrateController.php(103): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findUniqueIndexes(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
```

And here is my DB connection config:

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=api_template',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]
```

If it is not a bug in the framework, then what is the right way to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating a new instance of `Schema` without any config options.
looks like it's missing its `db` property.

i recommend you use instance provided trough `Yii::$app`

```
    $dbSchema = Yii::$app->db->schema;

    $myTableSchema = $dbSchema->getTableSchema('my_tbl');
    $uniqueKeys = $dbSchema->findUniqueIndexes($myTableSchema);
```

Comment: oh, I don't know that `getTableSchema` will automatically return the specific DBMS schema. Thus I don't need the `\yii\db\mysql\Schema` explicitly.